# c++ change of coordinates (Pixels 1920 x 1080 to 640 x 480)

Tags: c++, c++11, 2d

I am developing a small program that can draw a rectangle in different videos modes (for example 1920 x 1080 -> 640 x 480). I can resize a rectangle. But I am getting stuck, because I cannot find a clear method to achieve the problem. I am currently trying to create a matrix to perform a scale operation over the pixels but I cannot get the right answer. Part of the problem seems to be that `TransformMatrix::transform` is not scaling correctly.

```
#include <iostream>


typedef struct _Pixel
{
      _Pixel():X(1920)
      ,Y(1080)
      {}
      unsigned X;
      unsigned Y;
}Pixel;

    typedef struct TransformMatrix
    {
      constexpr TransformMatrix(const float aWeigth = 0.3f
                                ,const float aHeigth = 0.225f):W(aWeigth)
      ,H(aHeigth)
      {}
      void transform( const Pixel & aPixel)
      {
        auto x_value=static_cast<float>(aPixel.X)*W;
        auto y_value=static_cast<float>(aPixel.Y)*H;

        std::cout<<"x_value: "<<x_value<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"y_value: "<<y_value<<std::endl;

      }
      const float W;
      const float H;

    }TransformMatrix;

    int main()
    {
      Pixel aPixel;
      TransformMatrix _TransformMatrix;
      _TransformMatrix.transform(aPixel);
      return 0;
    }
```

The actual result:

> x_value: 576
>   y_value: 243

The expected result:

> x_value: 640
>   y_value: 480

How can I perform the right operation? Is it just a change of basis?
Should I scale only or also do a transformation operation?

Comment: Why don't you just use `opencv` ? There is a built in `resize` function

Comment: Multiply by the target resolution, and divide by the source resolution.

Comment: This is the rule you want to apply: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication

Comment: in other words, `aWeight = 640/1920`, `aHeight = 480/1080`

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef6681d763e363fc some style hints

Comment: @sehe you should really post this as an answer :)

Comment: thx  didierc, that was the answer, but i have recieved the notice that the image was fiited to 1920x 1080, so the original image, in 640x480, is now multiplied by a factor (2.25) to enlarge the heigth of the screen (HD 1080). so the calculattion for the image is well made, but the Image has an extra strip colorless to complete the full hd resolution

Comment: @vsoftco okay, I went the extra mile :)

Comment: Research "aspect ratio", which is the ratio of the height to the width. Scale your points by the target aspect ratio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wokay, since people urged me, let me explain the most important style improvements here:

- Naming: don't start names with underscores: It's illegal and the program invokes undefined behaviour
- struct tags: they're a thing of `C`, and obsolete in C++ ever since C++98
- Single Responsibility Principle - don't make the transform function print things
- Make the Pixel struct capable of printing itself (using `operator<<` for iostreams)
- Pure Functions: make `transform` return a modified value, instead of mutating the argument. In general this makes code a lot safer, and it can enable a class of optimizations. In the rare case where you wanted to update the pixel in-place you'd simply write

  ```
  pixel = transform(pixel); // the optimizer will see right through this
  ```
- Make `TransformMatrix` a calleable object (by implementing `transform` as `operator()` instead. This way, you can simply use it as a function, e.g. in an algorithm:

  ```
   std::vector<Pixel> poly1, poly2;
   std::transform(poly1.begin(), poly1.end(), 
         back_inserter(poly2), TransformMatrix());
  ```

  Which simply transforms all pixels in poly1 to poly2.

Exercise for the reader: name `TransformMatrix` so it does what it says. Right now, it's more like `ScalePixel`

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef6681d763e363fc)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>

struct Pixel {
    Pixel(unsigned x = 1920, unsigned y = 1080) : X(x), Y(y) {}
    unsigned X;
    unsigned Y;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Pixel const& p) {
        return os << "Pixel(" << p.X << ", " << p.Y << ")";
    }
};

struct TransformMatrix {
    constexpr TransformMatrix(float aWidth = 640/1920.f, float aHeigth = 480/1080.f) : W(aWidth), H(aHeigth) {}

    Pixel operator()(const Pixel &aPixel) const {
        return { static_cast<unsigned>(aPixel.X * W), static_cast<unsigned>(aPixel.Y * H) };
    }
    float W;
    float H;
};

int main() {
    Pixel aPixel;
    TransformMatrix xfrm;

    std::cout << aPixel << " -> " << xfrm(aPixel) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Pixel(1920, 1080) -> Pixel(640, 480)
```